# Convertir Python 3 a PHP?

Tags: php, python

Soy bastante novato, actualmente sé HTML, CSS, JS y muy poco de PHP.

Encontré este código en Github (Python 3) y quisiera saber cómo puedo pasarlo a PHP y que por ejemplo, pueda tener inputs como `usuario`, `contraseña` y algún botón de submit.

**Algo así:**

[image: ejemplo]

**No pido que me lo transcriban**, solo que me orienten en cómo puedo lograrlo. No importa que sea básico.

**Éste es el código:**

```
import requests,sys,optparse

class generate_token(object):
      def __init__(self,user,pwd):
          self.user = user
          self.pwd = pwd

      def __dir__(self):
          return self.generate()['access_token'],self.generate()['uid']
          
      def generate(self):
          r = requests.get(
            f'https://b-api.facebook.com/method/auth.login?access_token=237759909591655%25257C0f140aabedfb65ac27a739ed1a2263b1&format=json&sdk_version=2&email={self.user}&locale=en_US&password={self.pwd}&sdk=ios&generate_session_cookies=1&sig=3f555f99fb61fcd7aa0c44f58f522ef6'
          )
          if 'error_code' in r.json():
              print(f'\n\033[91m[x]\033[0m Erro_Message: {r.json["error_code"]}\n')
              exit()
          else:
              return r.json()

class Active(generate_token):

      def __init__(self,user,pwd,active=None):
          super().__init__(user,pwd)
          self.active = active

      def data(self,x):
          return 'variables={"0":{"is_shielded":%s,"session_id":"9b78191c-84fd-4ab6-b0aa-19b39f04a6bc","actor_id":"%s","client_mutation_id":"b0316dd6-3fd6-4beb-aed4-bb29c5dc64b0"}}&method=post&doc_id=1477043292367183&query_name=IsShieldedSetMutation&strip_defaults=true&strip_nulls=true&locale=en_US&client_country_code=US&fb_api_req_friendly_name=IsShieldedSetMutation&fb_api_caller_class=IsShieldedSetMutation' % (x,super().__dir__()[1])
      @property          
      def headers(self):
          return {
            "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization" : f"OAuth {super().__dir__()[0]}"
          }
      def request(self):
          r = requests.post(
            'https://graph.facebook.com/graphql',
            data = self.data(self.active),
            headers = self.headers
          )
          if 'error' in r.json():
             print(r.json()['error']['message'])
          else:
             if self.active == 'true':
                print('\n\033[92m[+]\033[0m  Your Profile Guard Has Been Enable √\n')
             else:
                print('\n\033[92m[-]\033[0m Your Profile Guard Has Been Disable √\n')


banner = '''\033[92m
 _________________________________________________
|                                                 |
|_________________________________________________|
|                                                 |
|         Code by : Fearless                      |
|                                                 |
|         Github  : https://github.com/fearless327|
|_________________________________________________|
|                                                 |
|_________________________________________________|'''

par = optparse.OptionParser(   
usage = '\nusage: python %prog --user (Your Email) --password (Your Password) --on/--off'
)
par.add_option(
    '--user',help='(Your Email Or Phone Number)',default=None,metavar='user@mail.ex'
)
par.add_option(
    '--password',help='(Your FB Password)',default=None,metavar='password'
)
par.add_option(
    '--on',help='Turn On Profile Guard',action='store_true'
)
par.add_option(
    '--off',help='Turn Off Profile Guard',action='store_true'
)
(arg,opt) = par.parse_args()

try:
     if arg.user != None or arg.password != None:
        print(banner)
        if arg.on:
           Active(arg.user,arg.password,active="true").request()
        elif arg.off:
           Active(arg.user,arg.password,active="false").request()
        else:
           par.print_help()
     else:     
        par.print_help()

except Exception as e:
     print(e)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()
```

Comment: Tienes que sber que python es un lenguaje que puede ser utilizado para crear distintos proyectos, encambio php solo se utiliza ennel backend de las páginas web y no hay una forma rápida o un programa para pasar ese código a php

Comment: Sería bueno que te des un paseo por [ask]. Tu pregunta muy probablemente termine cerrada por estar basada en opiniones (justamente estás pidiendo orientaciones). Si tienes algún problema _en concreto_ "convirtiendo" el código, edita tu pregunta para especificar los errores que has tenido.

Comment: @cristian, PHP es un lenguaje de propósito general y dado eso no está limitado solo a una faceta